# $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',.. called twice and more times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-events

For example, I have such simple snippet:

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $rootScope) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/AddNewOrder', {
    templateUrl: 'add_order.html',
    controller: 'AddOrderController'
      }).
      when('/ShowOrders', {
    templateUrl: 'show_orders.html',
    controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
      }).
      otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/AddNewOrder'
      });
}]);

sampleApp.controller('AddOrderController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is Add new order screen';

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log("Add new order");
    });
    
});

sampleApp.controller('ShowOrdersController', function($scope,$rootScope) {
    $scope.message = 'This is Show orders screen';

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log("Show orders");
    });
});
```

It is app.js from ng example, and in browsers it example looks so:

[image]

Full version you can see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jc3nFBAaBLMiGMYV4TZW?p=preview

Where is some strange:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log("Add new order");
```

and

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            console.log("Show orders");
        });
```

called twice on every click upon links.
Also I tried to use `$routeChangeSuccess`,but the result is the same.
Why does this happen?
And what needs to do to get a single call of `$scope.$on(..)`?

Comment: Are your links with hrefs in them? Cause that calls the routing obviously

Comment: Just check if you have included the controller twice (once in your state and once in your html as ng-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `href="#AddNewOrder"` to `href="#/AddNewOrder"`. 
Because of that  your controller initialized two times.